# How to find the probability of Non-convolution model tensorflow python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter

I have tried the following to find the `probability` of the model that I have created:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_outputs])
prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
```

Then while trying the epoch evaluation:

```
print ("Probability Training: ", prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: x_train,y:y_train}, session=sess))})
```

I am getting the following output in my jupyter notebook:

```
Probability Training:  [0 3 1 ... 2 2 2]
```

Which is not the probability but the **max values from the output** what I guess.

Kindly, help me find out the probability of the model. Please note that my model is not using `convolution` but a simple `LSTM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prediction` variable is an argmax evaluation, which will give you the index of the highest score. Going with a softmax instead should result in the desired output, since softmax transforms your scores into something that can be interpreted as probabilities:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_outputs])
probabilities=tf.nn.softmax(y)
```

You can still throw an argmax on top of the probabilities at a later stage to extract the most likely class

Comment: Hey Lukas, welcome to Stackoverflow. Thank you for your answer. I will check this and if it really met my requirement, then guess what I will accept your answer... :)

Comment: Just one query, is my argument as `y` correct or should I use the output of the predictions instead of the `y` which is the expected output for checking the predictions? Can you help me?

Comment: Is it possible to get a summed up probability of the output? Can you help me?

Comment: You will need to apply the `tf.nn.softmax` evaluation to your network's output, not the true labels. If I understand you correctly, you'll need to use the prediction output

Comment: What do you mean by summed up probability? The network with a softmax layer on top will return a probability for each possible class. Suppose you have 3 different classes, the output for a sample might be [0.6, 0.3, 0.1], meaning that the network predicts the probability for the sample being class 1 with 60%, class 2 with 30% and class 3 with 10%

Comment: Ok great to know. By summed up I mean, I want to get only only value for probability ... hence I tried `tf.reduce_mean` on top of the `tf.nn.softmax` I guess I am getting it now....  thank you for your help. Let me know if I am wrong anywhere I am always there to correct myself..... :)

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting what you try to do - summing up probabilities for different classes or different samples does not achieve anything in terms of insight. If you were to classify a sweet as either chocolate or jelly bean, averaging the probability of a certain sweet being chocolate of jelly bean gives you a value of 0.5 and tells you a grand total of nothing about the sample. I guess you could add up the probabilities for "is chocolate" for all samples to get a feeling for how much chocolate is in your samples, but that's a whole different story.

Comment: And Lukas, if you liked the questions here on Stackoverfow give upvotes to the question, It helps in building moral related to a relationship between the seeker and the people who ask queries. This helps to maintain a healthy environment on Stackoverflow. You can read these for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up and also this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300508/upvoting-questions-to-answers-that-help-you

Comment: Can you help me with that Lukas? means adding up and getting the values. A small indication or something in reference would help a lot.

Comment: Will do the reading on your links soonish. To your second comment: I would need to understand your problem in more detail to be able to answer your question. For a general understanding of the softmax layer I found the first part of https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/ quite useful

Comment: Hey lukas, can you help me get the confidence score of the model? It is the probabiity that I am talking about. Can you help me?

Comment: When using softmax output, the value for each class represents the model's confidence in the classification, which means that by accessing `predictions[tf.argmax(predictions)]`, you should get the confidence for each classification

Comment: Lukas where exactly I can put the statement you have specified? I am a bit confused. As I tried something like this: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/0c2d04fb464fad76cfdea7cc22973467

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179102/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-lukas-thaler).